# Adding figure in framed or shaded environment

Tags: floats, framed, wrapfigure

I am currently using the `shaded` environment from the `framed` package for large calculation digressions in my papers.

```
\usepackage{framed}
\newenvironment{digression}[1]{\begin{shaded} \noindent\textbf{\sc {#1}\\} }{ \end{shaded} } % or snugshade
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.9}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to include a figure within such a digression, I get the error `! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.`

I'm using tikz right now, but ideally I'd like it to be in a wrapfigure since it's such a small figure..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `figure`s are floating in nature, you can't use them inside a static environment. But the reverse can be done as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed,graphicx,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{shaded}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{shaded}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is interesting, although I really wanted to be able to use a wrapfigure which I don't think this is very applicable to. But thanks for the response.

Comment: @Hanmyo: If you provide a complete (non)working code starting from `\documentclass{..}` and ending at `\end{document}`, chances of getting a solution will improve.

Comment: Thanks, Harish. While trying to make an mwe, I realized that it actually does work. The problem must have been in my code elsewhere..