# background framed box with newenvironment "encadre"

Tags: framed, backgrounds, tcolorbox

I want to use a floating framed box that could be nicely placed in the text. `\fbox` needs to be placed by hand. I wrote this code which was exactly what I want to get...but with a floating object.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} 
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\newcounter{encadre}
\newenvironment{encadre}
\refstepcounter{encadre}\vspace{0.2cm}\textsc{\bfseries encadré \theencadre\ :}}
{\par\vspace{0.2cm}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\fcolorbox{Black}{Gray}{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
   \begin{encadre}\label{enc:metamere}
blabla
\end{encadre}
\lipsum[10]
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

So I use framed (impossible to install `mdframed` on my LaTeX version of 2009 on Ubuntu 12.04)

My question : Where must I  define `\defineshadecolor` as it is said in the framed documentation?

> framed doc p2 :"In fact, the “shaded” environment just redefines `\FrameCommand` to be `\colorbox{shadecolor}` (and you have to define the color “shadecolor”:
>   `\definecolor{shadecolor}`...)."

I tried to put it as an option or to write it like directly in the preamble, but it does not work. Here is the framed code, but without background.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{encadre}
\newenvironment{encadre} {\refstepcounter{encadre}
\vspace{0.3cm}\textsc{\bfseries encadré \theencadre\ :}}
{\par\vspace{0.3cm}}

\begin{document} 
\lipsum [50]

\begin{framed}
 \begin{encadre} test
 \end{encadre}\label{enc}
\lipsum[15]
\end{framed}


l'encadré \ref{enc} est à la page \pageref{enc}

 \lipsum 
\end{document}
```

Comment: `shadecolor` will only have effect if the `shaded` environment from `framed` is used, since you are not using it, `shadecolor` will do nothing in your code. In any case, you can define it using `\definecolor` (as in `\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{123,45,67}`) or `\colorlet` (as in `\colorlet{shadecolor}{red}`) .See the package `xcolor` documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot; I try that, putting \definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{123,45,67} in the preambule...but it has no effect, it is my problem. perhaps isn't it the write place to put it?

Comment: I try also `\usepackage[shaded]{framed}` but does not work

Comment: OK!! I just find it [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86205/adding-figure-in-framed-or-shaded-environment]

Comment: Yes, as I said in my comment, you need to use the `shaded` environment.

Comment: just to check again the Latex basics...

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution, thanks a lot to Gonzalo

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[francais]{babel}
 \usepackage{lipsum, caption, xcolor, framed}
 \definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{140,20,21}
 \newcounter{encadre}
 \newenvironment{encadre} {\refstepcounter{encadre}
 \vspace{0.3cm}\textsc{\bfseries encadré \theencadre\ :}}
 {\par\vspace{0.3cm}}

\begin{document} 
\lipsum [50]
\begin{framed}
   \begin{shaded}
      \begin{encadre} test     
      \end{encadre} 
    \lipsum[15]
   \end{shaded}
\end{framed}
\lipsum 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot to define `shadecolor` in your example.

Comment: Another solution is the package tcolorbox [link]http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox [link] Very nice, works well

Answer (score 0):

Here and example of "Encadré" box with  package tcolorbox. I do not know why, but it needs the package to be in the same folder than the .tex file. It does not work if the tcolorbox.sty is the usual location (for me /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex)

```
documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum, xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{encbox}[2][]{%
colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
title=Encadré.~\thetcbcounter: #2,#1}
\begin{document} 
\chapter{boite}
\begin{encbox}{Boite tbolorbox}
\lipsum[30]
\end{encbox}
\end{document}
```