Shaded area for answers breaking with figures and \textwidth
I'm trying to make a small package that will shade some areas for answers in some notes I'm doing and so far I have this
\ProvidesPackage{solutions}

\newif\ifsolutions
\solutionsfalse
% If solution is false the environment should blank whatever is inside it
% If true it should shade the background gray
\DeclareOption{solutions}{\solutionstrue}
\DeclareOption{nosolutions}{\solutionsfalse}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{framed}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution} { +b }
{%
  \ifsolutions
    \par
    \noindent
    \definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.85}
      {%
        \begin{shaded}%
          #1%
        \end{shaded}%
      }%%
  \fi
}{}

The problem is two fold, I have to put some figures (tikz graphs with captions) in which the shaded environment breaks, and the width of the shaded area is bigger than \textwidth)
Example, first paragraph is okay, second with items and enumerate the shaded version fills the whole page leaving a ton of white space shaded to the left.
Then below that is a simple tikz graph, first one fails using shaded (because of the \figure) the second one works.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amscd, amssymb, amsthm, latexsym, amsfonts}
\usepackage[Algoritmo]{algorithm}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=4cm,headheight=2.2cm,textheight=22cm,hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[solutions]{solutions}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}

\begin{document}

 \lipsum[1]
 
  \begin{solution}
       \lipsum[1]
  \end{solution}


\subsubsection*{\textit{Section}}


\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2]
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item \lipsum[3]
  \end{enumerate}

 \begin{solution}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=$\alph*)$,ref=$\alph*)$, listparindent=1.5em]
    \item \lipsum[5]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[4]
    \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{solution}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{solution}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{figure}[h!]

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={20mm}, main/.style = {draw, circle}] 
    \node[main] (s) {$s$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{center}
    \caption{Test}
    \end{figure}
\end{solution}

\begin{figure}[h!]

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={20mm}, main/.style = {draw, circle}] 
    \node[main] (s) {$s$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{center}
    \caption{Test}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}


Since figures are floating in nature, you can't use them inside a static environment.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86205/adding-figure-in-framed-or-shaded-environment

You can use \captionof{figure}{...} (caption or capt-of packages) without a figure.  You can even put it inside a tikz node (with [text width=...]).  Note, it should go inside some environment to prevent a global definition of \@captype.

@NonnoDino but I want to have more than a figure inside it without the shaded area being split, I'll edit my example.

you can put your environment inside the figure, if that would work. or you can not use a figure. but asking latex to put a figure inside solutions is making contradictory demands. think of it this way: a figure is a float. so it floats (potentially) somewhere else. so, if you want a shaded area to apply to stuff inside the figure, you have to put the shading into the figure. otherwise, the figure will float off somewhere and only the shading will be left behind.
